# OracleDB: COALESCE and ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle, coalesce

I use `COALESCE`function to avoid ORA-01427 and [pick up first non-null value](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php).

```
COALESCE((
        SELECT c.SCounts
        FROM counts c
        WHERE c.ID = 10000
        ), 0)
```

When I comment this code everything works well.

Comment: what is the primary key (or unique key(s)) on this table? I'm betting the counts.id column is not unique, and therein lies your problem. Also, where is this code being used? I'm assuming it's in the select list of an outer query? (i.e. `select coalesce((<your query), 0), <other columns> from ...`)

Comment: Thanks, I already found problem. `Coalesce ((my_subselect), 0)`. subselect returns more then one value

Comment: It will return one value for one row, but if you select from a table without WHERE you will get many rows. Anyway, could you please accept my answer below if that was the real problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the above COALESCE is embedded into a SELECT something like this:

```
SELECT
COALESCE((
        SELECT c.SCounts
        FROM counts c
        WHERE c.ID = 10000
        ), 0)
FROM counts
```

If this is true, then the problem could be that this select will return as many rows as table COUNTS has.